# Tooling api sObject type 'ProfileLayout' is not supported

Tags: apex, tooling-api

I have a component that dynamically replicates a page layout . Im querying the ProfileLayout object to get the layout JSON, this works fine when i run as a sys admin, but fails when executed as a non-admin, getting this response:

> {"message":"sObject type 'ProfileLayout' is not supported.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}

this is the query:

```
string query = 'select Layout.Name from ProfileLayout where ProfileId = \'' + UserInfo.getProfileId() + '\'';
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The tooling API is generally unsuitable for non-admins. Perhaps the UI API or REST API would be better suited to your needs?

Comment: I looked at the UI api but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the correct layout for the running user based on Profile/RecordType when creating a new record, its fine for an existing record as i can pass the record ID in

Comment: Have you explored the Apex `Metadata` class? It supports layouts, but I am not sure if it will support your use case.

Answer (score 3):

The describe call you're apparently looking for is:

```
/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/<ObjectName>/describe/layouts/<recordTypeId>
```

This will give you all the layout information need for a given record type and object type. This call is available for all users so long as they have any API access.

Comment: Hello@sfdcfox I guess this is not working at 2020 https://gyazo.com/e4409af426e746a16206321ed8afaaee

Answer (score 0):

I used by mistake the wrong URL - `/data/{apiVersion}/query?q=''` instead of `/data/{apiVersion}/tooling/query?q=''`, maybe this also applies to your case.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
/services/data/v49.0/tooling/query?q=select+LayoutId,+RecordTypeId,+TableEnumOrId+from+ProfileLayout+where+ProfileId+=+'00e0p000000WhKwAAK'
```

Notice that the string `/tooling` is in the URL. Without this bit, it hits the error.